# How to define a common interface for a group of string enums to be used by another class interchangeably

Tags: swift, enums, interface

I want to do this or something like it to get the same functionality 
could someone help?

```
protocol FilterEnum: CaseIterable {
}

enum SomeFilterEnum: String, FilterEnum {
   case owner = "Owner"
   case karat = "Karat"
}

class SomeCls {
    private let filterTypes: [FilterEnum]

    init(filterTypes: [FilterEnum]){
        self.filterTypes = filterTypes
    }

    func useFilterTypes() {
       for type in filterTypes{
           print(type.rawValue)
        }
    }
}

let sm = SomeCls(filterTypes: SomeFilterEnum.allCases)
```

Answer (score 1):

Judging from your usage, you need this common interface to be both `CaseIterable` and `RawRepresentable`. Well, that is `CaseIterable & RawRepresentable`, but we can't use that as a type directly because they both have associated types. We have to introduce a generic parameter on `SomeCls`:

```
class SomeCls<T> where T : CaseIterable & RawRepresentable, T.RawValue == String {
    private let filterTypes: [T]

    init(filterTypes: [T]){
        self.filterTypes = filterTypes
    }

    func useFilterTypes() {
        for type in filterTypes{
            print(type.rawValue)
        }
    }
}
```